# Show PHP file inside a DIV with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 3 files

- register.php
- reg.js
- reg.php

When I hit the submit button in register.php (looks like this)

```
    <div id="phpcontenthere"></div>

    <form action="reg.php" method="post" id="myForm">

    <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Sth'>

    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="reg.js"></script>
```

It shows the error messages of reg.php but in another window.
I want those error messages to be shown inside the register.php.

And the reg.js looks like this:

```
$("#submit").click( function() {

    $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
        $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
        function(info) {

            $("#phpcontenthere").empty();
            $("#phpcontenthere").html(info);

        });
    $("myForm").submit( function () {
        return false;
    });
});
```

Maybe this solution i want to create is not good, or it's good but i missed something I don't know, but I would be really happy if anyone could help me,

Thanks in advance!

Tibor

Comment: This question needs more info.  First off, what do you mean, "in another window"?  The browser isn't spontaneously going to pop up a new window.  You have to tell it to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'll teach you the logic, with sample code as I don't want to spoon-feed you.

Firstly, create an array called 'errors':

```
$errors = array();
```

Then while you have your checks, just inflate your array.

```
if(something) {
  $errors[] = "Error description";
}
```

Then once all your errors are inflated, you check for the length, and if it is greater than 0 errors, then return the array.

```
if(count($errors) > 0) {
  return $errors;
}
```

And then, you can display the array with the for loop.

```
$c = count($errors);
for($i=0; $i < $c; $i++) {
    echo $errors[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems.

First, `$("myform")` should be `$("#myform")` -- you forgot the `#` so it wasn't matching the ID.

Second, you shouldn't define a handler for `submit` inside the `click` handler; event handlers should almost always be defined at the toplevel.

You should just put `return false` in the `click` handler. Or better, put all that code in the form's submit handler (clicking on the submit button submits the form).

```
$("#myForm").submit( function() {

    $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
        $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
        function(info) {
            $("#phpcontenthere").html(info);
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

It's also not necessary to call `.empty()` before calling `.html()`, since the latter completely replaces what's there.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you are still submitting the form (the piece of code that returns false when trying to submit is inside the click listener). Maybe that's why it is ignoring the return false, and indeed submitting the form (instead of posting it with ajax)

So you should try a javascript code like this:

```
$("#submit").click( function() {
    $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
        $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
        function(info) {
            $("#phpcontenthere").empty();
            $("#phpcontenthere").html(info);
        }
    );
});

$("#myForm").submit( function () {
    return false;
});
```